# Prevent data deletion if an app cleard all data or removed in android

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I an working with an app, where user get a gift on first start of the app.

User doesn't have to register an app.

I need to remember, if the user have already used the app or not.

If I use shared preferences, a database, a file to store flag about user's first using, they will be deleted after the app removing or after data clearing.

How can I persist an information about user's using of the app and don't lose this information after app deletion/data clearing?

Comment: Anything that your app puts on the device is either removed upon uninstallation or is in a spot where the user can remove it.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's ok, if the user can delete it manually, but it is not good to remove it automatically after app deletion.

Comment: then you can write it in external storage ,https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: @Breair Sabir, i thought about that, but it brings permissions processing. It ruines all design idea.

Comment: There is this thing called `autobackup` you can check it out here, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup